# What does "sudo ./xampp-linux-x64-5.6.3-0-installer.run" do?

Tags: linux, syntax, terminal

I know what sudo does I just have no idea what "./" does I have done a bunch of research and have come up empty. What does this the `“./”` do  in `“sudo ./xampp-linux-x64-5.6.3-0-installer.run”` do in the Linux terminal?

Comment: `.` is the current directory, `/` is the directory separator.

Comment: what is the point of specifing the current direcory. Why wouldn't `xampp-linux-x64-5.6.3-0-installer.run` work

Answer (score 0):

`.` means current directory

`./xampp-linux-x64-5.6.3-0-installer.run`  means you are trying execute the executable `xampp-linux-x64-5.6.3-0-installer.run`  from current directory

```
sudo ./xampp-linux-x64-5.6.3-0-installer.run
```

means you are trying to run the executable from current directory using root previlege

Comment: what is the point of specifing the current direcory. Why wouldn't `xampp-linux-x64-5.6.3-0-installer.run` work

Comment: if your current directory is not part of environment variable  $PATH, system does not know where from to invoke the executable, so you have to specify the path of the executable file. When you run a command in *NIX systems, system will search for the executable in all the directories specified in $PATH environment variable and if it didnt find that command in none of the directories will show command not find error.